# ClickHouse: is there a way to do arrayJoin( DictGetArray( ...) )

Tags: clickhouse

With ClickHouse, I do analytics on multi-valued dimensions. This is very easy to do with the `arrayJoin` function. For example:

```
SELECT arrayJoin(places) AS place, count() FROM hits GROUP BY place
```

Now let's get into dictionaries. I store the field `personId` as a column and use a dictionary to map `personId` to the person's (first) name. If want to count hits by name, all I have to do is:

```
SELECT dictGetString('persons', 'name', personId) AS name, count() 
FROM hits GROUP BY name
```

My specific use case is people with several (first) names. I would like to combine `arrayJoin` and dictionaries. The code I imagine would look like:

```
SELECT arrayJoin(dictGetStringArray('persons', 'names', personId)) AS name, count() 
FROM hits GROUP BY name
```

`dictGetStringArray` doesn't seem to exist. And anyway I don't know how to map to an array in a dictionary.

**Is there a functionality in ClickHouse about this? Is there a kind of workaround or method to do it?**

(note: my use case is not really "persons" and I don't care if it works for strings or any other type :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the array join clause. I think you will find your solutions - something like:

```sql
SELECT person_id, count
FROM hits
ARRAY JOIN persons AS person_id, 
    arrayMap(lambda(tuple(x), dictGetString('persons', 'names', x)), persons) as name
GROUP BY name
```

The idea is to apply dictGetString to each member of the array. The above is based on the documentation below. Sorry could not reproduce it because I don't know how to use dictionaries in clickhouse!

See docs here - good luck:

https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/select/#array-join-clause

Comment: The problem is the function dictGetStringArray does not exist.

Comment: Sorry I meant to put in dictGetString - edited it now.